# How to "touch" a nested object with Leapmotion AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, leap-motion

Lets say I have a movieclip with multiple objects nested inside.

Which is the best technique to get a touch on an object inside the Movieclip?

Example:
I have a Movieclip named "ast" (parent), a nested MC called "green" (child/parent) and a button named "butt" inside green (child).

I want to SCREEN_TAP "butt".

I tried this:

```
if(pointX >= this.ast.green.butt.x &&
               pointX <= this.ast.green.butt.x + this.ast.green.butt.width &&
               pointY >= this.ast.green.butt.y &&
               pointY <= this.ast.green.butt.y + this.ast.green.butt.height)
{ trace ("your butt is touched!");}
```

But the result is a negative "touch". No trace.
Any idea in how to detect this?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the touch point coordinates are in stage coords, you will have to use localToGlobal() on the button's x, y, x+width, y+height. Or you will have to add up all the parent objects' coordinates (more work).

Or you could also use hitTestObject()/hitTestPoint() and check it with that.